# Pandas: create a new df from another df contains specific value within group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, group-by

I have a df:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['James', 'James', 'James',
           'Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max',
           'Park', 'Park', 'Park',
           'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom'],
    'From_num': [78, 420, 'Started', 298, 78, 36, 298, 'Started', 28, 311, 'Started', 60, 520, 99, 'Started'],
    'To_num': [96, 78, 420, 36, 78, 78, 36, 298, 112, 28, 311, 150, 520, 78, 99],
    'Date': ['2020-05-12', '2020-02-02', '2019-06-18',
             '2019-08-26', '2019-06-20', '2019-01-30', '2018-10-23',
             '2018-08-29', '2020-05-21', '2019-11-22',
             '2019-04-12', '2019-10-16', '2019-08-26', '2018-12-11', '2018-10-09']})
```

And it looks like this:

```
       ID From_num  To_num        Date
0   James       78      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420      78  2020-02-02
2   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
3     Max      298      36  2019-08-26
4     Max       78      78  2019-06-20
5     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
6     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
7     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
8    Park       28     112  2020-05-21
9    Park      311      28  2019-11-22
10   Park  Started     311  2019-04-12
11    Tom       60     150  2019-10-16
12    Tom      520     520  2019-08-26
13    Tom       99      78  2018-12-11
14    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
```

I wish to create a new dataframe for each ID (person's name) that either one column contains number 78 within the group (no matter 78 appears in From_num or To_num or both), and remove the person BOTH columns doesn't contain 78, in this case 'Park'. I have wrote code like this:

```
find_nn = df2.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x[['From_num', 'To_num']].isin([78]).any())
find_nn.columns = ['from_bool', 'to_bool']
find_nn['bool_result'] = find_nn['from_bool'] | find_nn['to_bool']
bool_nn = find_nn['bool_result'].reset_index()
df2_new = pd.merge(left=df2, right=bool_nn, on='ID', copy=False)
df2_new = df2_new[df2_new['bool_result'] == True]
```

It is working but very redundant and slow, as in my real case the dataset is more complex. If you have any better ideas please help. Many thanks!! Expect like this:

```
       ID From_num  To_num        Date
0   James       78      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420      78  2020-02-02
2   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
3     Max      298      36  2019-08-26
4     Max       78      78  2019-06-20
5     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
6     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
7     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
11    Tom       60     150  2019-10-16
12    Tom      520     520  2019-08-26
13    Tom       99      78  2018-12-11
14    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to get the same data. You can apply 2 filters to df2. The first line is saying, filter df2 where either From_num or To_num = 78, then get the IDs of these rows.
And on the next line we filter df2 by those IDs.

```
ids = df2[(df2.From_num == 78) | (df2.To_num == 78)]['ID'].unique()
df2_new = df2[df2['ID'].isin(ids)]
```

Comment: Thank you @ruby, right your code is also quite fast. Many thx

Answer (score 7):

Let us try `filter`

```
df1 = df2.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x : x[['From_num','To_num']].eq(78).any().any())
       ID From_num  To_num        Date
0   James       78      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420      78  2020-02-02
2   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
3     Max      298      36  2019-08-26
4     Max       78      78  2019-06-20
5     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
6     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
7     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
11    Tom       60     150  2019-10-16
12    Tom      520     520  2019-08-26
13    Tom       99      78  2018-12-11
14    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
```

For speed

```
m=df2[['From_num','To_num']].eq(78).any(axis=1).groupby(df2.ID).transform('any')
df1=df2[m]
```

Comment: thank you@YOBEN_S for the answer, way way much better than mine, just wondering is your code faster than @Scott Boston 's?

Comment: on my laptop, Scott's is slightly faster

Comment: @XaviorL try the transform one ~

Comment: Thanks @YOBEN_S, I think your old one is faster, in my real case, 10k rows of data

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good one for you:

```
df2[df2['ID'].isin((df2.set_index(['ID','Date']).stack() == 78).any(level=0).loc[lambda x:x].index)]
```

Output:

```
       ID From_num  To_num        Date
0   James       78      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420      78  2020-02-02
2   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
3     Max      298      36  2019-08-26
4     Max       78      78  2019-06-20
5     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
6     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
7     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
11    Tom       60     150  2019-10-16
12    Tom      520     520  2019-08-26
13    Tom       99      78  2018-12-11
14    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
```